# Warning: Illegal string offset 'Ticket_no' in line 131

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
                        foreach($ticket as $t)
                        {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $t['Ticket_no']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $t['name']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $t['Roll']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $t['branch']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $t['hostel_id']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $t['Indisciplinary_desc']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $t['reporting_date']; ?></td>
                        <td><input id="actionyes" type="submit" value="Yes"/>
                            <input id="actionno"type="submit" value="No"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        }
                        ?>
```

i'm trying to repeat the row as the data is inserted in db.so i have run foreach loop but it is giving me warning not output so please anyone help me in this warning.

```
<?php

$query="SELECT i.Ticket_no,i.Roll,i.reporting_date,i.Indisciplinary_desc,r.hostel_id,s.branch,s.name FROM indisciplinary_dc_reports i,room_allocation1 r,student s WHERE i.Forward_status=0 AND i.roll=r.roll AND i.roll=s.roll AND r.end_date>NOW() AND i.Closure_status=0";
$query_run=mysql_query($query,$db);
if(mysql_num_rows($query_run)==False)
{
   echo "No Pending Records.";
}
else
{
    $ticket=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run);
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you `print_r($ticket);`? May it's `$t['id'];`

Comment: or lower case or ...

Comment: `mysql_num_rows($query_run)==0`?

Comment: Check to see if your query isn't failing you `$query_run=mysql_query($query,$db) die(mysql_error());`

Comment: it's running then but gives same result 7 times in every row if i echo  $ticket

Comment: then try a `while` loop instead. `while ($t = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){...}`

Comment: wht condition i give in  whileloop?

Comment: reload my comment above, I made an example. That should work. However, using `mysql_fetch_array()` might have been what you would need to use, but try my example.

Comment: giving error :Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular syntax like this:

```
while ($ticket=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
    echo $ticket['Ticket_no'];
...other fields...

}
```

This is how mysql_fetch_assoc works

> Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row and
>   **moves the internal data pointer** ahead. mysql_fetch_assoc() is equivalent to calling mysql_fetch_array() with MYSQL_ASSOC for the
>   optional second parameter. It only returns an associative array

So it has a pointer and you can't use it more than once in another loop.

Also

> Warning
>
> This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP
>   7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.